# How can we print 2 tables with all columns in psql using single query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

We `SELECT` data from multiple tables in mysql or SQL Server with `SELECT * FROM table1, table2;`.

But in pgAdmin this query does not work like it should be.

Can anyone tell me how can I get my desired output with this or there's any mistake in this logic?

Comment: Well, what do you expect? You are doing an (implicit) cross join between the two tables. This should result in the same thing regardless of the database being used. [Postgres](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bfeb9a96264261af8b46ad7027a60715) [SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bfeb9a96264261af8b46ad7027a60715) [MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bfeb9a96264261af8b46ad7027a60715)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming both tables have the same number of columns (and preferably the columns are ordered and labelled similarly...)

```
select * from table1
union all
select * from table2
```

Comment: Thanks alot it works, but this is for same number or columns. What about i both tables have different number of columns?

Comment: This works for same number of columns and same data types in those columns. In order to get mismatched tables to work you have to explicitly name your columns (replace the * with column names) and where one table has a column and the other doesn't then put a null in that column.